# Push Notification from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to send notification when data change in my Cloud Firestore database. I have this fields [image]

I need to get the all users tokens and send the push notification. I have a code, but this only give me a token if i know the user name this is my code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('notification/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Message from Cloud',
                body: 'This is your body',
                badge: '1',
                sound: 'default'
            }
        };

        admin.firestore().collection('notification').doc('fcm-token').get().then(doc => {
            console.log("Token: " + doc.data().user1.token);
        });

    });
```

Comment: I hope you don't intend to store all your users' tokens in a single document.  That won't scale at all.  You might want to think about how to structure you data so that your strategy can work.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all users in the document:

```
admin.firestore().collection('notification').doc('fcm-token').get().then(doc => {
  let data = doc.data();
  Object.keys(data).forEach((user) {
    console.log("Token: " + data[user].token);
  });
});
```

But as Doug commented: storing the tokens for all users in a single document is bound to become a scalability problem at some point.

Comment: this show me an error 

TypeError: Object.key is not a function
    at admin.firestore.collection.doc.get.then.doc (/user_code/index.js:22:20)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: Oops... that's a typo: `Object.keys()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys